# I can't get the value userCount from the onDataChange method in ValueEventListener so I can use it in my getItemCount method inside my Adapter Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

this is my Adapter class

```
class Adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>() {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Adapter.ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.new_message_user, parent, false)
    return  ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Adapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return 5
}

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    var userImage: ImageView
    var userName: TextView
    init {
        userImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.circle_image_view)
        userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_database)

        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val position: Int = adapterPosition
        }
    }
}
}
```

and in the same file, I have this function fetchUsers() which will get me the number of my app users from firebase, it's getting the job done getting the right number of users in the Log

```
fun fetchUsers() {
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users")
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val countUser = snapshot.childrenCount.toInt()
        Log.d("countUsers", "FirebaseUsers: ${countUser.toString()}")
        
    }
    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
})
}
```

now I know that I can't use userCount outside onDataChange method,
so is there any way to get userCount so I can use it in my Adapter inside getItemCount,
I tried using callback but didn't get it right, I tried declaring countUser as a variable globally and set it to 0 as so

```
var countUsers: Int = 0
```

so when I run the app the first time I enter the activity it still shows 0, but if I go back to the previous activity and then enter it again it shows the right number of users.

Comment: Have you tried declaring `countUser` globally?

Comment: I see how it could be helpful, but how am I gonna reassign the value from the onDataChange method to the global variable?

Comment: the onDataChange method returns a Unit and never returns an Int so I can't see how it's ever gonna work

Comment: is `fetchUser()` method declared inside `Adapter` class?

Comment: no it's not, I aslo tried declaring it in another activity but still the same problem. I tried using callbacks but didn't work, seems like a big problem that no one can solve

Comment: I tried declaring countUser as a variable globally and set it to 0 as so `var countUsers: Int = 0` so the first time I enter the activity it still shows 0, but when I run the app if I go back to the previous activity and then enter it again it shows the right number of users.

Comment: Share the latest code and I'll fix it for you.

Comment: I just updated my question. @UndefinedBug1.0